# how to navigate to another view after clicking on tableview rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS Development. I am trying to implement grouped `tableView` (static). I do not know how to give an action, I mean on clicking a tableView cell in any section it has to navigate next `ViewController`.

[Here is screenshot I created in StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfqDM.png)

What code I have to write in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to achieve this.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
UIViewController*vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCid"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:true completion:nil];
```

OR push if you embed the root inside a navigationController

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:true];
```

Give the VC this identifier in IB **VCid**

//

You need to make it single selection instead of no selection , also you don't have to create outlet for the tableView inside the class , as it's available default inside any `UITableViewController` as `tableView`

[image]

Comment: what is happening is that, I m not able to select the row

Comment: here is project link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZbS9xbi-9sjVcjzSw0-Q7AKTvAfxCZb0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: OMG..! Due to that selection, it was not worked. Now it is working.